# how to manipulate objects using Seed button in real time

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

I cut a mesh into some random (N number) shapes. I also used random.seed(). So every time I run the code, I get new set of patterns.

Now, I want to do it with "UI Panel" with some variables as input buttons (such as MyInt, MyFloat, dropdown list, etc; don't know, if they are correct), so that I can change them accordingly and get their results in real time.

Small example: If I change the seed value and run the code, I get another pattern. So this pattern changing should be get done with seed button in 'UI Panel' in real time.

If my question is not clear, I will be eager to modify it and make it more understandable.
[image]
This Gif image shows a "Plane" divided into 4 new Planes as specified by:

```
percent_list = [40, 40,10,10]
```

I also highlighted:

```
random.seed(3)
```

So, if I have a Panel like in Gif which I have edited in Ms-Paint. Whenever I change

```
bpy.props.IntProperty(name="seed")
```

value, it should change the random.seed() and eventually change my Plane object in the scene.

I hope my question is now clear. or?

Comment: Do you need to know how to make the panel, or how to make the properties, or both?

Comment: Both, if you can show me in easier way.

Comment: After thinking about it, I still don't get what you're trying to do, like why do you need to make properties if you're trying to adjust properties that already exist?

Comment: I have added a gif file for more understanding. Since I have a big code, I am uploading just a snap of it, so that a general idea can be cleared.

Comment: Ok, re-answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define some properties, and then make a panel to display it them. I've cut and pasted from the templates in Blender's Text Editor(look here for many more examples).

First make an update function that will run every the properties change:

```
def update_function(self, context):
    myfloat = context.scene.myfloat
    myint = context.scene.myint
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        #your code would go here
        print((myfloat, myint))
```

Then define some properties with your function as the update. [More information on properties here.](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.props.html)

```
bpy.types.Scene.myfloat = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="My Float", update=update_function)
bpy.types.Scene.myint = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="My Int", update=update_function)
```

Then the panel:

```
class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_mypanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, "myfloat")
        row.prop(context.scene, "myint")
```

Now we put it all together and register the panel and properties:

```
import bpy

def update_function(self, context):
    myfloat = context.scene.myfloat
    myint = context.scene.myint
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        #your code would go here
        print((myfloat, myint))    

class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_mypanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, "myfloat")
        row.prop(context.scene, "myint")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__) #registers all the classes
    bpy.types.Scene.myfloat = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="My Float", update=update_function)
    bpy.types.Scene.myint = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="My Int", update=update_function)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.myfloat
    del bpy.types.Scene.myint

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: But, how can I manipulate it. for example if I save 'myint' property as 'y' and use it in bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0,y,0)). And then when I change the IntProperty in the Panel, I am getting error.

Comment: What is the error?  That operator is expecting a tuple of floats, not an integer.

Comment: yes it is expecting a tuple. But how can I manipulate any object in the scene (transform.translate: for example). Without hitting the Operator. For example: when I change 'myint' property in 'UI' how it directly update the position of object in the scene. I am trying to control objects in the scene with these properties. But I do not know how.

Comment: This wasn't stated in your question. You didn't post any code, so I couldn't know what you were doing with the properties. Give me a while and I will update my answer.